# What is the name of this song used in the "shed tears of scarlet" scene of Cowboy Bebop?

Tags: music, cowboy-bebop

I am curious to know what the song in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gr2YZU_rtBA) is (the song in the *"And you will shed tears of scarlet"* scene from `Session 25: The Real Folk Blues (Part I)`). I have traversed the Cowboy Bebop OSTs but to no avail. I hope one of you here could help me out.

Comment: The reason I made that edit is so that if/when the video gets removed from Youtube, future readers will have some idea what scene you were talking about. I strongly recommend that you edit your post to contain some concrete indicator of what scene or episode you're referring to other than the Youtube link.

Comment: Fair enough. You can edit it back if you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like I missed a track while scavenging through the OSTs. The name of the song is ***Road to the West*** and is by Yoko Kanno/The Seatbelts (track 15 from OST 3: [*Cowboy Bebop Blue*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_of_Cowboy_Bebop#Cowboy_Bebop_Blue)).

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gmFAJPArhqM) is the Youtube video for the song.